# Pandas integer colums remove last three digits

Tags: pandas

A pandas df as an example with columns all integers but some are with NAN.

`raw
capitalSurplus  188883000
totalLiab   2589242000
totalStockholderEquity  6740732000
minorityInterest    27549000
otherCurrentLiab    40412000
totalAssets     9357523000
endDate     1483142400
commonStock     5818867000
retainedEarnings    732982000
otherLiab   746117000
otherAssets     6034000
totalCurrentLiabilities     436539000
propertyPlantEquipment  9135741000
totalCurrentAssets  212758000
longTermInvestments     2990000
netTangibleAssets   6740732000
netReceivables  201288000
longTermDebt    1406586000
accountsPayable     396127000
otherCurrentAssets  NAN`

ps. df is transposed.

expect results are last three digits('000') are removed from all columns despite NAN columns

and also keep endDate unchanged:

```
endDate     1483142400
```

Comment: Colin, I have added an answer per your requirements, please let me know if it helps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `NAN` is not a `np.nan` , you can replace them using `df.replace`.

Post which , I renamed the columns as `A,B` by using `df.columns = ['A','B']`

Then you can just do the below using [floordiv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.floordiv.html) which is a builtin function:

```
df.B.update(df[df.A!='endDate']['B'].floordiv(1000))
```

This will remove the last 3 zeros except the endDate row and update the column B in the respective indices.

Alternatively you can also use `//` to remove the last 3 zeros as shown below:

```
df.B.update(df[df.A!='endDate']['B'] // 1000)
```